Developing a model with two clauses using a select output block
The select output block has a parameter that takes the values 0 or 1. The condition is "agent.parameter" == 0. Depending on this, the path true or false is selected. However, in my model, one branch is always selected, regardless of the value of the parameter. What can it be connected with?
We tried several methods, expecting that both branches would be considered by AnyLogic, but it seems to consider only one branch at a time.
All the logic behind the block is considered and, although the question seems quite obvious and standard, there is certainly more to that.
Btw, the AnyLogic version is PLE.
Adding delay block did not help also.

this question has been asked at least 100 times in stackoverflow so you should have been able to find something... but this might help you
https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/select-output-misbehaving
